# Krull dimension and algebraic extensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an algebra over a field $k$ and let $\bar k$ be the algebraic closure of $k$. Is it true that the Krull dimension of $A$ equals that of $A\otimes_k\bar k$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that $A$ is finite type over $k$. If you want to consider more general situations, let me know and I can edit my response.

Since Krull dimension is unaffected by passing to the maximal reduced quotient, we may as well assume that $A$ is reduced. Moreover, we may as well assume that $A$ is, in fact, integral since we can just work irreducible component by irreducible component.

Then, since $A$ is integral and finite type over $k$, we know that there is a finite surjection

$$\text{Spec}(A)\to\mathbb{A}^n_k$$

where $n=\dim(A)$. This is the content of Noether Normalization. Then, by passing to $\overline{k}$ we get a finite surjection

$$\text{Spec}(A\otimes_k\overline{k})\to\mathbb{A}^n_{\overline{k}}$$

which easily implies the result.

Comment: Dear Alex: yes,  could you please edit your response so as to include the case where $A$ is not of finite type?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I see you've called my bluff. :) I thought I had an idea for when it's not finite type, but now I'm concerned. Namely, we can, of course, write our ring as a direct limit of finitely generated subalgebras. Each of these *should* have dimension at most $n$, and so I was hoping I as just going to google "Krull dimension of direct limit" and there would be a nice answer. There wasn't. It's probably true that the direct limit has Krull dimension bounded by the factors, but the proof eludes me for now. Do you have something nice to say on the topic? Thanks! :)

Comment: Dear Alex, no, I have nothing nice to say about the non finitely generated case: that's why I was interested in your proposal. However if you allow arbitrary extensions of  the base (not just  algebraic closures) , then the Krull dimension may change: for example $k(T)$ has Krull  dimension 0 but $k(T)\otimes_k k(T)$ has Krull dimension 1.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes! I am well-aware of your nice MO post about this topic. :) Maybe nothing particularly nice can be said? Certainly tensoring with $\overline{k}$ can cause some wacky things to happen, even if dimension is not altered (e.g. $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is non-Noetherian). I'll amend this answer if I find anything out!

Comment: Anyway thanks a lot for addressing my comment, Alex.